# How to find rotation and translation of a triangle made of 3 points with 3 infrared leds

Tags: c++, opencv, rotation, geometry, translation

I am working on a project, where i have only 1 static camera (not moving) but an object plane with 3 points on it (its a flat plane, so the difference of the points in the z direction is zero). The camera is always on the same position and the plane moving and rotating in the space. I have calibrated the camera with 25 chessboard images and the function:

```
calibrateCamera(object_points, image_points, image.size(), intrinsic, distCoeffs, rvecs,      tvecs);
```

and the undistortion works fine. Now i made opencv (c++) to write the intrinsics and distCoeffs into an xml file.

How can I use these parameters in a new program, to finds 3 points which form a triangle (made with infrared- leds), and return me the rotation and translation of this triangle?

Comment: And what is your question exactly ? Are you asking for code?

Comment: Sorry, jonsca edited my text. My question was in this missing text: "But now I am stuck. Any suggestions how to continue?? :(

Thanks in advance,

Escore." I dont need code, but maybe some instructions/ commands which i should google to know how to continue from this point on. Thank you!

Comment: Please dont all edit my text!! See how this makes problems?

Comment: [Questions and answers](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#editing) can be edited by other users with enough reputation. This is done in an effort to improve the quality of posts and make them useful to others that find there way here in the near or distant future with similar problems. Sometimes information gets lost or the post is misunderstood by the editor. You are always able to edit your own post if you find an edit changes its meaning. I hope the question I added at the end captures your intent. If not please edit. Understand that "Any suggestions how to continue?" is not a good question.

Comment: You did fine Dave Rager, but your predecessor did not even add a question mark. I am not mad, but if people edit my post i hope they take effort to do so. (sorry for my english btw)

Comment: If your triangle is rotationally unique, this is a trivial problem, identify the vectors and you have it. If it is NOT rotationally unique, you clearly have multiple solutions and you can align the vectors however you choose

Comment: I'm sure you first know how to locate the points using OpenCV. Points = vectors (no normalizing needed because you said they are always the same distance) = steps i outlined above

Comment: Ok so first I find the points in the image, which should be no problem  after I google this a bit. But then, (these 3 points are mounted on a plate, and I rotate the plate),then i calculate the distance between this points. And the lenght of the distance of the points to each other tells me the roation and translation. Lets say i always see this triangle from the side and it moves towards the camera about 200mm and roates about 30° arround its internal axes. Now i dont have any clue which functions i need to do this. If i found the lenghts, how do i continue? Brute it? No chars left. Thx

Comment: have you looked at [cv::getAffienTransform](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/geometric_image_transformations.html)?

Comment: Hammer - Thanks for the hint, I looked at it now, but I can't figure out how to use it, maybe because my technical english is not that good. Could you please go more into detail? One thing I thought about was something like "reverse central projection"..but yea..

Comment: Ah, and i found something called Posit. http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/Posit

Comment: Ok, i found out that posit is not good for my project, because it needs at least 4 coplanar points.. Please help me, any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## 2D case

**This part of the answer only discusses rigid motions *in the plane*, so it doesn't fully match the question.**

Suppose you have identified your points, which seems to work according to [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12916645/how-to-find-rotation-and-translation-of-a-triangle-made-of-3-points-with-3-infra#comment17501624_12916645). Now you can compute the distances between these points and order them. The shortest distance between two detected points should correspond to the shortest edge of your original triangle and so on. With this information, you can label your points as *A*, *B* and *C*.

Next, you move (translate) all points so that one point lies at the origin afterwards. This is assuming that your original triangle has one corner at the origin. Let us assume that *A* is at the origin, both in your original triangle and in the moved set of points. The negated version of this vector indicates the **translation** of your triangle.

Now for rotation. Assume for the moment that for your original triangle, *B* is located at the positive *x* axis, i.e. has *y* = 0 and *x* > 0. Now you can take the (moved) position of the point *B* from your camera, and using `atan2` of its coordinates, you can determine the angle between the line *AB* and the *x* axis. So that's the angle of **rotation** for your triangle.

You can combine both of these to form an affine transformation. If your original triangle is not located with *A* at the origin and *B* on the positive part of the *x* axis, then you can use similar techniques to determine how your original triangle relates to one that has the described properties.

## 3D case

For rigid motions in space, I have no ready-to-use solution. Only an idea. Suppose your camera is located at the origin, and the image you analyze is embedded at *z* = 1. Then a point (*x*, *y*) in the image corresponds to a point (*x*, *y*, 1) in that embedded location, and the ray passing through that point is given by multiples of that coordinate, i.e. (*λx*, *λy*, *λ*). So starting from the locations of points *A*, *B* and *C* in your image, you can compute the corresponding points in space, based on a single variable per point, e.g. *a* through *c*.

Now your task is to choose these three variables in such a way that the distances between the points in space match the edge lengths of your triangle. This leads to a system of three equations in three variables:

```
(a - b)^2 + (Ay*a - By*b)^2 + (Ax*a - Bx*b)^2 == AB^2
(a - c)^2 + (Ay*a - Cy*c)^2 + (Ax*a - Cx*c)^2 == AC^2
(b - c)^2 + (By*b - Cy*c)^2 + (Bx*b - Cx*c)^2 == BC^2
```

Unfortunately, these equations aren't linear. There are squares of your variables all over the place. Simply feeding them into a computer algebra system hasn't yielded an explicit solution for me yet. I guess there might be numeric methods to find an approximation using some iterative process, but you'll have to do some research on that.

Once you have the 3D coordinates, computing the transformation from these should be simple by comparison. It all depends on the format you desire for the description of a rotation.

Comment: This is only for 2D Translation and Rotation, right? I need 3D Translation and Rotation for every axis/point. Where i think the easiest way is, i translate its center and rotate the triangle arround the medians afterwards. One method i thought of was using the simplex algorithm (or any other like that). Thanks for your answer!

Comment: What would also be helpful is to know how i can get the projection matrix (i have intrinsic and distortion) from calibrateCamera. I want to calculate from 3d points to the points on the picture..

Comment: This is 2D only, yes. I misread yor question. Not sure whether 3D reconstructionis even possible given three points only. The degrees of freedom seem barely sufficient in case you know which point is which, but I guess there is a reason POSIT requires four.